# How to find with a condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying to find data with:

```
     await User.find({$or: [{email: req.body.email}, {linkedEmail: req.body.email}]})
     .populate("roles")
     .exec((err, user) => {
         if (err) 
            res.status(500).send({message: err});
      });
```

The user always has an email registered and maybe could contain a linked email... So I'm trying to find it both ways but when I test it in postman it just loops in *Sending request* and not show a response

Comment: Looks like you're close. Does the code above works in certain situation? For exemple if the user **has** an `email`?

Or does it never work? Do you have an error?

Maybe try to console.log just this part `await User.find({$or: [{email: req.body.email}, {linkedEmail: req.body.email}]})`

Comment: @Cohars only when I try with findOne({email: req.body.email})

Comment: Could you try with mongoose's query builder ? `await User.find().or([{email: req.body.email}, {linkedEmail: req.body.email}])`

Comment: @Cohars It works! tysm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the mongoose query builder can avoid some confusion. See [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or)

Also, since you're using async/await, you should use probably use try/catch instead of passing a callback to exec. cf [doc](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html)

```js
try {
  const user = await User.find()
    .or([{ email: req.body.email }, { linkedEmail: req.body.email }])
    .populate('roles')
  // ...
} catch (err) {
  res.status(500).send({ message: err })
}
```